# Not able to fetch dashboards data over API in superset

Tags: api, dashboard, rbac, apache-superset

I am trying to fetch **superset dashboard data over API**.

First I am logging into the superset over the API `api/v1/security/login`, passing the parameters,
`{
"username":"Superset_USERNAME",
"password":"Superset_PASSWORD",
"provider":"db"
}.

I get the access token as the response.

Have used the access token as a bearer token in the request to fetch dashboards from the superset. Dashboard request route `api/v1/dashboard/{id}`

But I am getting a forbidden response.
[Response from superset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLolQ.png)

I have enabled dashboard RBAC feature flag in  `"DASHBOARD_RBAC": True,` in the superset_config file.

If I disable the `Dashboard_rbac` or add a `public role` in the dashboard, I get the API response, and no auth is required, and that leads to a security issue.

Is there any way to fetch the dashboards over API without adding the `public` role to the dashboard or not disabling the `dashboard_RBAC`